# ASP.NET Core HealthChecks

Tags: c#, .net, health-check

Can anyone please explain what the "timeout" param does in `.AddUrlGroup()`?

Is it the timeout of **httpClient** - meaning how long it will wait for the response from that endpoint?

Or the frequency at which this Url will be pinged?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I understand the code, there are several timeout values that you can configure. On the one hand, there is the "global" timeout that the parameter references. If no specific timeouts are set, this value is also used for the timeout of the HTTP requests. See this [link](https://github.com/Xabaril/AspNetCore.Diagnostics.HealthChecks/blob/7b69de9ee3a4a2e8619b72015858bb16d6982f14/src/HealthChecks.Uris/UriHealthCheck.cs#L5) for the code.

In addition, you can configure a timeout for each URI that you want to query. If this is set, it overrides the global timeout.

Also, the [health check itself uses the global timeout value](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/a450cb69b5e4549f5515cdb057a68771f56cefd7/src/HealthChecks/HealthChecks/src/DefaultHealthCheckService.cs). Therefore, if you want to query several URIs and the first on times out, the health check as a whole will timeout.

The timeout parameter does not define the interval that the check is run for.